# What does "Pronounced legs" mean in a beer style?

Tags: beer-styles

Was reading the BJCP guide for Eisbock and noticed they mention something about this particular style does not have a lot of head but has a "pronounced leg", as in:

> Pronounced legs are often evident

Never heard this term until now and was wondering what they mean by this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand it, this term comes from the wine world, where it refers to the patterns the glycerine makes on the inside of the glass. Glycerine (glyceryl alcohol or glycerol) is decidedly thicker than ethanol or water, so it forms a clear syrupy ring from which droplets or streamers trail down toward the surface of the beverage.

Here's an image of leggy wine I [found on the 'Net](http://thewinoandiknow.typepad.com/the-wino-and-i-know/2010/10/my-wine-as-nice-legs.html):

[image: Legs in a glass of red wine]

http://thewinoandiknow.typepad.com/the-wino-and-i-know/2010/10/my-wine-as-nice-legs.html

Comment: +1 Eisbock (Ice Bock) is a high ABV beer where ABV is concentrated from freezing and removing water from the finished beer. The high ABV reduces head retention and helps give it legs, like the wine image above. But it needs the body to support it too. You will can generally see legs in most med-full body styles above 10% ABV. Wee Heavy, Barley Wines, RIS etc.

Comment: This is pretty interesting, since I've seen 8% beers forming legs... I think the lowest ever, was a session (hydromel) mead with 7%ABV...

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of this in the beer world but in the wine world "legs" are formed as the liquid moves down the glass after being swirled or having been drank. The appearance is different than lacing from a beer as legs appear as long drooping lines and lacing (as you know) resembles lace-y material and appears more like dried foam.